# How to set last three bit of a byte efficiently?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

I want to set the last three bit of a byte to a specific vaue. What’s the best way to archive this goal?

I can think of at least two solutions… Let’s assume I have the following Byte: 1101 0110 and want to set the three last bits to 011.

Solution 1:

```
 1101 0110
&1111 1000 //and with mask to clear last three bits
|0000 0011 //add the target bits
```

Solution 2:

```
 1101 0110 >> 3 //shift right to remove last three
 0001 1010 << 3 //shift left to clear last three
|0000 0011 //add target bits
```

Is there a better/shorter/more efficient way?

Comment: Without a doubt the performance impact will be infinitesimal. But this question is more about my passion for coding things in the most efficient way. So the increasement of speed may really small, but is that a reason to write it the slower way, when doing it fast ist just a question of a few more or less chars in code...?

Comment: The problem with these optimizations is that they are highly architecture dependant. What is fastet on x68 is not fastest on tricore. Your architecture manual should be able to provide you with information of number of cycles taken for a shift vs the number of cycles needed for a &.

Comment: Look, just do it the obvious way, the easy-to-understand way.  The easy-to-debug way.   99.9% of all houshold developers would use bit masks immediate and move on to design decisions that matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to say

```
b = (b & ~7u) | 3
```

because `3=0...011` and `7u=0..111` in binary, and the complement of `7u` is `~7u=11...1000`, so the operation does what you want. It first clears the last three bits (by doing `b & ~7u`) and then sets the first and the second bits (by doing bitwise-OR with `3`).

Comment: moreover, these two solution are really "low instructions". There are fastest way to do it, shifting and logic operations are really fast for the proc. Any other way to do it will be really slower.

Comment: last **three** bits: mask should be ~7u or 7u

Comment: Your solution (bitmask + OR) looks like my first solution. So is bitmasking with AND faster than two times shift?

And one more question - why does the mask be 7u and not 7? Because it has to be unsigned for building the complement?

Comment: I don't know but it is more intuitive; I guess it depends on the CPU how many cycles it takes to do a shift vs. AND. Regarding the `u`, yes.

Answer (score 2):

If the C source code has a `>>` in it, that does **not** mean the generated code will have shift instructions.

`((x>>3)<<3) | 3` *may* generate the exact same code as `(x & ~7) | 3`.  Compilers are very sophisticated in their optimization.

Use what is simplest [@Martin James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422143/how-to-set-last-three-bit-of-a-byte-efficiently#comment60461520_36422143).

Recommend [@blazs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36422303/2410359) solution, as that is simple to understand and well copes with signed integer issues.

```
(x & ~7u) | 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do your second solution, sure it depends on your hardware architecture but almost always SHIFT operations are faster than ADD.